# How to send message through websocket connection to aws connect chat?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-connect

I am adding page in my flutter app for support , so user can ask there question and there is no any login requirement for that ,I did websocket connection so user can send message and get the messages from flow , but I am unable to send message

```
Future<void> _sendMessage() async {
  final String message = _messageController.text;
  try {
    final payload = {
      'content': message,
      'contentType': 'text/plain',
      'type': 'MESSAGE',
      'participantToken': _participantToken,
    };
    _channel?.sink.add(json.encode(payload));
    print('Message sent: $message');
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle WebSocket send error
    print('WebSocket send error: $e');
  }
}
```